How to get apk bundle version from play console in android studio?
How to get apk bundle version from play console in android studio?
In want apk version from play console for custom app update dialog.Any one has idea for that How to get apk bundle version from play console in android studio?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Select your app in the console, then on the left pane:

Test and release > App bundle explorer > Select the version you're interesed in -> Downloads

This section will allow you to download the signed universal APK which will work on all supported architectures. If you need an APK for a specific device you can try searching for it down below.
